# Programmatically getting tags (keywords) from titles, descriptions and related items

Tags: php, tags

First I need to programmatically get tags (unlike what is done here on stackoverflow) from the titles and descriptions of my posts. I don't want commonly used words to appear in keywords. Is there an efficient way of doing this?

After getting good tags, I would like to save them in MySQL DB.

Now, how do I **efficiently** get related posts using these automatically created tags? E.g. What is done here.

Comment: i dnt need to provide code, im just trying to work up an algorithm...whats with the -1. damn

Comment: Your question is extremely vague. For example, you don't indicate what sort of application you are working with. Without some specifics, terms like "tags", "posts", "keywords" are meaningless.

Comment: @Jeff, i might not be a pro of tags.... that is exactly why im asking the question in the first place. so that my members are not forced to type tags

Comment: @Sir You should accept answers you believe correctly addressed your question. Like you just did on this question. Read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: :-), i really needed to read that faq. cheers people

Comment: It is a valid question that has probably been asked before. You probably want to search for "tag generation", "generate tagcloud", etc. Here is a related but more specific question that has been asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314821/rails-dynamic-tag-generation-from-context

Comment: @Kai Chan thanks for that but i think i will do whats done here. give users options to specify tags with hints. i dnt know or use ruby for that autotag specified

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look up [tf-idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf). You're looking for terms with a high tf-idf score.

Comment: @Getr G, wow that looks very complicated but seems to be the best way. any simpler ways of doing this? how is it done here on stackoverflow? do u know?

Comment: @Sir: it's done *manually* on SO. Like how you did when you asked this question, and how I did when I just removed two bogus tags from your question.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise against using this method. You can use it to *suggest* tags, but automatic tagging will be very, very hard to implement correctly and accurately.

One of the reasons for that is because computers don't understand semantics. Take any question here and try doing that. It will not work 95% of the time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing an online API service might help. Check:

OpenCalais - try pasting an article here: http://viewer.opencalais.com/

Or Yahoo's Term Extraction API: http://developer.yahoo.com/search/content/V1/termExtraction.html

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how this would be possible without you having some sort of list.. how would your app know what words to use and not use? I suppose you could find a thesauraus that you could API into and use this to find tags, it would get rather complex, if you're looking to do it for SEO reasons, you could make the app look for words based off a keyword list, such as one you get from google keyword tool..

as far as how to do this, I use PHP all the time and think its great for building web apps but for this sort of thing, (processing of a lot of text data, regex, etc) I tend to have problems in PHP, maybe its just me, but I prefer using perl

Answer (score 0):

Headup may also help with this task (just as Open Calais). You can check it out here, and see if it works for you:

http://labs.headup.com/Services/RealTime/API/EntitiyExtraction/Playground.aspx

If needed, there's also an API.

(Disclaimer: I'm a developer @SemantiNet and work on this product... We'd love to help).

Good luck!